# Why does IDatasetContainer2.CreateDataset fail with ArcObjects at ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, data, network, arcgis-runtime

I have a small application used to check and generate network, created with the help of the following tutorial:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/a...00000w7000000/

It worked just fine with ArcGIS 10, but since I had to upgrade to 10.1, the application fails on this line:

```
INetworkDataset networkDataset = (INetworkDataset)datasetContainer2.CreateDataset(deDataset);
```

The error code is "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled Message=Exception from HRESULT:
0x80042262", which really isn't helpful. Is there something new I could have missed, or some help on what could cause such an error ?

Comment: Are you calling `ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind` as shown in the [closest facility solver sample?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//004800000226000000)

Comment: Yes, I have used this method in several small applications and the others still work with 10.1.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was finally solved and it had nothing to do with this particular function, the origin was a database insertion that failed without error message. As a result, the database used with our solver wasn't complete like expected and the CreateDataset failed.